# Conditional probability question in Markov process proof

Tags: solution-verification, stochastic-calculus, conditional-probability, markov-process, stochastic-integrals

From textbook Introduction to Stochastic Integration written by Hui-Hsiung Kuo,
one equation is very unclear to me. The content of the part is quoted below. My question is that: in the middle step, author says that
$$
P\left(X_{t}^{s, Z} \leq y \mid \mathcal{F}_{s}\right)=\left.P\left(X_{t}^{s, x} \leq y\right)\right|_{x=Z} \quad \forall y \in \mathbb{R}
$$
So why is it true? I believe the key fact is the connection between $X_t^{s,x}$ and $X_t^{s,Z}$. I know that $X_t^{s,x}$ being independent of $\mathcal{F}_{s}$ will be needed when I try to eliminate $\mathcal{F}_{s}$, but this seems to be not enough for the equation.

> In this section we will study some properties of the solution of the stochastic differential (or rather integral) equation in Equation (10.3.1), namely,
> $$
> X_{t}=\xi+\int_{a}^{t} \sigma\left(s, X_{s}\right) d B(s)+\int_{a}^{t} f\left(s, X_{s}\right) d s, \quad a \leq t \leq b,
> $$
> where $\sigma$ and $f$ satisfy the Lipschitz and linear growth conditions. We first prove that the solution $X_{t}$ is a Markov process.
> Let $\left\{\mathcal{F}_{t} ; a \leq t \leq b\right\}$ be the filtration given by the Brownian motion $B(t)$, namely, $\mathcal{F}_{t}$ is defined by $\mathcal{F}_{t}=\sigma\{B(s) ; s \leq t\}$. Obviously, the solution $X_{t}$ is adapted to this filtration.
> Let $s \in[a, b]$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be fixed and consider the following SIE:
> $$
> X_{t}=x+\int_{s}^{t} \sigma\left(u, X_{u}\right) d B(u)+\int_{s}^{t} f\left(u, X_{u}\right) d u, \quad s \leq t \leq b .
> $$
> To avoid confusion with the solution $X_{t}$, we use $X_{t}^{s, x}$ to denote the solution of the SIE in Equation (10.6.1). Since the initial condition $x$ of Equation (10.6.1) is a constant, we see from the approximation procedure in the proof of Theorem 10.3.5 that the solution $X_{t}^{s, x}$ is independent of the $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{F}_{s}$ for each $t \in[s, b]$. If follows that for any $\mathcal{F}_{s}$-measurable random variable $Z$, we have the equality
> $$
> P\left(X_{t}^{s, Z} \leq y \mid \mathcal{F}_{s}\right)=\left.P\left(X_{t}^{s, x} \leq y\right)\right|_{x=Z}, \quad \forall y \in \mathbb{R}
> $$
> In particular, put $Z=X_{s}$ in this equation to get
> $$
> P\left(X_{t}^{s, X_{s}} \leq y \mid \mathcal{F}_{s}\right)=\left.P\left(X_{t}^{s, x} \leq y\right)\right|_{x=X_{s}}, \quad \forall y \in \mathbb{R}
> $$
> Now, since $X_{t}$ is a solution of the SIE in Equation (10.3.1), we have
> $$
> X_{t}=X_{s}+\int_{s}^{t} \sigma\left(u, X_{u}\right) d B(u)+\int_{s}^{t} f\left(u, X_{u}\right) d u, \quad s \leq t \leq b .
> $$
> But $X_{t}^{s, X_{s}}$ is also a solution of this SIE. Hence by the uniqueness of a solution, we must have $X_{t}=X_{t}^{s, X_{s}}$. Thus Equation (10.6.2) can be rewritten as
> $$
> P\left(X_{t} \leq y \mid \mathcal{F}_{s}\right)=\left.P\left(X_{t}^{s, x} \leq y\right)\right|_{x=X_{s}}, \quad \forall y \in \mathbb{R}
> $$
> which is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-field generated by $X_{s}$. Therefore, we can conclude that
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> P\left(X_{t} \leq y \mid X_{s}\right) &=E\left[P\left(X_{t} \leq y \mid \mathcal{F}_{s}\right) \mid X_{s}\right] \\
> &=P\left(X_{t} \leq y \mid \mathcal{F}_{s}\right), \quad \forall s<t, y \in \mathbb{R}
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> Then by Lemma 10.5.9, the stochastic process $X_{t}$ is a Markov process. Hence we have proved the next theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Stochastic Calculus by Paolo Baldi, page 94, we have the following lemma:

> Lemma 4.1 (The freezing lemma) Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathrm{P})$ be a probability space and $\mathscr{G}$ and $\mathscr{D}$ independent sub- $\sigma$-algebras of $\mathscr{F}$. Let $X$ be a $\mathscr{D}$-measurable r.v. taking values in the measurable space $(E, \mathscr{E})$ and $\psi: E \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ an $\mathscr{E} \otimes \mathscr{G}$-measurable function such that $\omega \mapsto \psi(X(\omega), \omega)$ is integrable. Then
> $$
> \mathrm{E}[\psi(X, \cdot) \mid \mathscr{D}]=\Phi(X),
> $$
> where $\Phi(x)=\mathrm{E}[\psi(x, \cdot)]$.